# i can't display the first row of the file

Tags: c++, file

i have a coding that read from a file. My problem right now is the output didn't display the first row of the file. i also cannot find the smallest value. but i already got the highest value . This is my coding :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void total (ifstream & theFile);

int main()
{
    ifstream theFile("data.txt");

    if (!theFile)
    return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1;

    total(theFile);
}

void total (ifstream & theFile)
{
    theFile.clear();
    theFile.seekg(0);

    int year {}, classA {}, classB {}, classC {};
    theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC;

    int sum;
    int high_year;
    int highest_sum;
    int low_year = year;
    int lowest_sum = sum;


    for (int year {}, classA {}, classB {} , classC {};
    theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC; )

    {
         int sum = classA + classB;

         highest_sum = sum;
         high_year = year;

        if ( sum > highest_sum )
       {
          highest_sum = sum;
          high_year = year;
       }
       if ( sum < lowest_sum )
       {
          lowest_sum = sum;
          low_year = year;
       }

    cout << setprecision(5);
    cout << " Year :" << year << " Number students  : " << sum << endl;

    }

    cout << "    Highest number students is " << highest_sum << " at " << high_year << endl;
    cout << "    Lowest number students is " << lowest_sum << " at " << low_year << endl
}
```

the value of class A,B and C is in integar. for example the input is like :

2012  35  32  30

2013  34  32  34

2014  32  30  29

and it continue until 2020. the output should display all the year will total student then display which year has total student highest and lowest. something like

2012 97

2013 100

if 2013 is the highest then it will display
The highest number students is 100 at 2013

Comment: What is the input and output, expected output?

Comment: Try to remove the first `theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC;` statement before the for loop.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin sorry i look at the data wrongly . Your suggestion work for both of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row is swallowed by the first `theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC;`, so remove this line we will get the first row.

The `clear` and `setg` are not needed here, since the file stream is newly created.

The duplicated definition values can be removed to make the code clear.

For max and min value check, we need to set the default value:

- For default max value, we set `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`
- For default min value, we set `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

A fixed program may be like this:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void total(ifstream& theFile);

int main() {
  ifstream theFile("data.txt");

  if (!theFile) return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1;

  total(theFile);
}

void total(ifstream& theFile) {
  int high_year;
  int highest_sum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  int low_year;
  int lowest_sum = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  for (int year{}, classA{}, classB{}, classC{};
       theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC;)

  {
    int sum = classA + classB;

    if (sum > highest_sum) {
      highest_sum = sum;
      high_year = year;
    }
    if (sum < lowest_sum) {
      lowest_sum = sum;
      low_year = year;
    }

    cout << setprecision(5);
    cout << " Year :" << year << " Number students  : " << sum << endl;
  }

  cout << "    Highest number students is " << highest_sum << " at "
       << high_year << endl;
  cout << "    Lowest number students is " << lowest_sum << " at " << low_year
       << endl;
}
```

Comment: alright but can i ask about the first row that swallow by the  theFile >> year >> classA >> classB >> classC; ?

Comment: i has done a coding that have a highest function and lowest function that get data from a file. for highest funtion it work when i didn't use theFile >> . But for smallest function , it get 0 if i don't use it . Any idea why ?

Comment: @kimsjk Have you tried my program? I have tested it locally, the min value is right. The problem is that the default value for the min value should be larger than the actual values, then after comparing we will set it to a smaller value.